# excel interop : NumberFormat #,##0.000 doesn't display the expected result

Tags: c#, excel, interop, number-formatting

I developed a C# utility class called ExcelGenerator that generate a List of objects to excel. I want to display double numbers in this format : 3 288,523.

NumberFormat = "#,##0.000" doesn't display the expected result

This is the method :

```
public void FormatNombre(string frm)
{
_excel.Selection.NumberFormat = frm;
}
```

and this is the call :

eg.FormatNombre("#,##0.000");

Number still displayed like this : 3288,522.542

Answer (score 1):

You want to format 3288523.542 to 3 288,523?

Try something like this:

```
[>999]#" "###","###;#
```

Edit:
Just noticed looks like you are trying use French: Try this format.

```
# ##0,000
```

Comment: Hi Chris, it works fine for big numbers having Thousands but for Numbers like 943,901,  it becomes 944.

Comment: remain as it is. I want display Thousands white separator for Only numbers having Thousands.

Comment: Excuse me i lease office and i will reconnect in home. Thanks.

Comment: Just noticed looks like you are trying use French:  Try this format.  # ##0,000