# Gridview to Excel not yielding any results in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, gridview

I hope someone can put me on the right track. I need to download my Gridview to Excel:

the Gridview appear on my .ascx page with no issue ... I press the button the following code is excuted, i get the prompt to save or open, but then I get that the "file.xls" is not in the correct format or corrupted, I press OPEN ... and nothing appears in my Excel. i remember having to do this before and I had trouble... what am I missing:

```
protected void dwnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=kbNotification.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            //Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
            GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: Beside some formatting problem that I have resolved, look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251162/gridview-export-to-excel-formatting-problems, there is a method that is working fine to export datagrid to excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my Gridview was in an .ascx page ... the default.aspx page had to contain two parts: in the code behind:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
            return;
        }
```

and in the default.aspx in the top <%@page - EnableEventValidation="false"

this was necessary to handle the gridview in that needed to be between  tags.

also, for some dumb reason I had  tags on my .ascx page... which needed to be taken out.

then what made this work finally was using the following code, for OnClick event:

```
protected void dwnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=kbNotification.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            //Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
            GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
```

I was missing the Response.Write ... oops!

now my Excel is displaying the contents of my screen.
I hope this helps someone else who may be experiencing the same issues.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the output isn't a true excel spreadsheet.  It's essentially a formattable HTML/Text file that will need to be saved as an excel spreadsheet after export.

Comment: well, it does work except that I keep getting the message "the file you are trying to open is in a different format that specified by the file extension